# 403 Error when redirecting with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ftp, chmod

I have a directory on my website called `/ftp` where I have installed net2ftp on the server so that I may more easily access my website's files from anywhere. The problem I am having is that I am trying to make the htaccess redirect to `/ftp/index.php` with

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

however, when I go to `/ftp` it shoots a `403 Forbidden Error`. I have all of the directories leading up to it chmodded to 777 as well as `/ftp` and the `.htaccess` file (in `/` and `/ftp`) and it still has the 403 error. Strangely enough, when I manually type in `/ftp/index.php` it will display the login page for the ftp client.

If anyone could help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the forward slash. Use `DirectoryIndex index.php` instead. Also, make sure that .htaccess is enabled in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: I fixed it, never mind. Apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my .htaccess to this and now it works:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ftp

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```